# regular expressions in perl for extracting information

Tags: regex, perl

How would I match any number of any characters between two specific words... I have a document with a block of text enclosed between 'begin parameters' and 'end parameters'. These two phrases are separated by a number of lines of text. So my text looks like this:

```
begin parameters
<lines of text here \n.
end parameters
```

My current regular expression looks like this:

```
my $regex = "begin parameters[.*\n*]end parameters";
```

However this is not matching. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `/s` switch so that the any character `.` will match new lines.

I also suggest that you use non greedy matching by adding `?` to your quantifier.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = do {local $/; <DATA>};

if ($data =~ /begin parameters(.*?)end parameters/s) {
    print "'$1'";
}

__DATA__
begin parameters
<lines of text here.
end parameters
```

Outputs:

```
'
<lines of text here.
'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current regular expression does not do what you may think, by placing those characters inside of a character class; it matches any character of: ( `.`, `*`, `\n`, `*` ) instead of actually matching what you want.

You can use the `s` modifier forcing the dot `.` to match newline sequences. By placing a capturing group around what you want to extract, you can access that by using `$1`

```
my $regex  = qr/begin parameters(.*?)end parameters/s;
my $string = do {local $/; <DATA>};
print $1 if $string =~ /$regex/;
```

See [**Demo**](https://eval.in/164493)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
Begin Parameters([\S\s]+?)EndParameters
```

Translation : This will look for any char who is a separator, or any char who is everything but a separator (so actually, it will look for any char) until it find "EndParameters".
I hope it is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The meta-character `.` loses its special properties inside of a character class.

So `[.*\n*]` actually matches 0 or more literal periods or zero or more newlines.

What you actual want is to match 0 or more of any character *and* 0 or more of a newline. Which you can represent in a non-capturing group:

`begin parameters(?:.|\n)*?end parameters`